# How to pass the anti-forgery token an action method with the HttpDelete attribute in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Is this even possible?

Code looks like this ...

```
[Transaction]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Delete(int id) { ...}
```

Comment: is a HTTP DELETE operation by a browser even possible? or is this a REST API?

Comment: I'm using ExtJS using restful conventions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the following helper to the form:

```
<%= Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete) %>
```

This will include a hidden field which will instruct the framework to invoke the proper controller action. Now there are two possibilities:

1. Normal html form submit: only POST is supported so this is what will be used but thanks to the hidden field the proper controller action will be invoked
2. AJAX: you could use any verb you want including DELETE to serialize the form input values and send them - no problem here.